# Install FreeDOS via Bootcamp

Tags: mac, bootcamp

Is it possible to run FreeDOS via Bootcamp on a Mac?

If so, what are the instructions for doing so?

Comment: I assume you were not able to instal FreeDOS to either internal disk. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

There were a few housekeeping chores that I preformed before booting from the FreeDOS DVD. I have both Yosemite and El Capitan installed on my Mac. To avoid SIP problems, I chose to preform the chores while booted to Yosemite. SIP was still enabled, but Yosemite ignores the SIP settings. I assume you can use El Capitan with SIP disabled.

I required the partition, that I chose to install FreeDos, to meet certain requirements.

1. The partition must be formatted MS-DOS (FAT) by the Disk Utility
   application. Note: Later when installing FreeDOS, I reformatted the
   partition again.
2. The partition must appear in the the Master Boot Record (MBR)
   partition table. The contains of the this table can be displayed by
   using the following command.

   ```
   sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0
   ```

   If you are installing on a second internal disk, then replace
   `disk0` with `disk1`.
3. The id shown in the MBR table for this partition must be `0C`. This
   usually occurs after formatting the partition as MS-DOS (FAT). In my
   case, I first had to format the partition as "Mac OS Extended
   (Journaled)", then format as MS-DOS (FAT). This must be a bug in the
   Disk Utility.
4. The partition must be flagged as active in the MBR table. By
   "active", I mean "bootable". The active partition is marked with an
   asterisk `*` character in first column of the output from the

   ```
   sudo  fdisk /dev/disk0
   ```

   command. You can use the

   ```
   sudo  fdisk  -e  /dev/disk0
   ```

   command to change the active partition. The proper interactive
   command is `flag`.

> Note: More information on the `fdisk` command can be found by entering the command `man  fdisk` or online [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdisk.8.html).

I also had additional requirements.

1. The Mac needs to be set to boot using legacy mode. This can be done
   with the `bless` command. In my case, I was installing to the 4th
   partition on disk 0, so I used the following.

   ```
   sudo  bless  --device  /dev/disk0s4  --setBoot  --legacy
   ```

   The `0` represents `disk0` and the `4` represents the 4th partition.
   Actually, when booting in legacy mode, the partition is chosen by
   the bootstrap code stored in the MBR. It is safe to assume this code
   will choose the partition set active in the above step 4. So when
   booting, the partition value set by the bless command will be
   ignored.
2. The MBR must contain valid bootstrap code or no bootstrap code. OS X
   is installed without this code. This is why you see the warning
   message below when using the `fdisk` command to change the MBR.

   ```
   fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
   ```

   When I installed FreeDOS, the MBR contained the bootstrap code that
   was being used by Windows 10.  You can view the contents of your MBR
   by using the following command.

   ```
   sudo  hexdump  -C  -v  -n  512  /dev/disk0
   ```

   If you are unsure if the bootstrap code in your MBR is valid, you
   can zero out this memory by using the following command. The
   bootstrap code occupies hex addresses 0 through 1B7.

   ```
   sudo  fdisk  -u  -f  /dev/zero  -y  /dev/disk0
   ```

At this point, you should be able to start installing FreeDOS using the DVD. I chose to install everything.

When I reached the display shown below, the computer seemed to freeze. In reality, the computer was just taking a long time to install software. More that just the Kernel is being installed here. This is why the progress bar does not seem to change.

[image: web]

Also, in some of the subsequent steps, I needed to press the space bar several times before the installation would proceed.

When reached the step associated with the display below, I chose `1`.

[image]

Comment: My purpose for installing FreeDOS is to be able to run SpinRite on my Mac. Unfortunately, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc. block much of what SpinRite does. I was simply hoping to find a solution that would eliminate the need to pull the drive out of the machine and hook it up to a PC.

Comment: @ericgorr: I assume then there is something physically wrong with your internal hard disk? Otherwise, what would be the point of needing SpinRite? Also, what is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: My hard drive appears to be operating just fine. I simply want to be able to use SpinRite for it's problem prevention and maintenance capabilities. Mac Pro Mid 2012.

Comment: @ericgorr: I updated my answer. I would try to create a USB FreeDOS flash drive installer from the FreeDOS iso. Let me know if you succeed and I will further update my answer.

Comment: Good work. Keep in mind, the system tracks revisions, so rather than putting Update 1, update 2, etc.. Just edit the post to contain a clear answer and either move the troubleshooting to the bottom of the post or remove old information entirely.

Comment: I am running El Capitan. I do have a DVD drive. Additionally, I have an advantage of having a second internal HD (250gb) which I can dedicate in part or in whole for this purpose. I can format it however I like. I can certainly create my own bootable DVD. Can you describe how, exactly, you did that?

Comment: @ericgorr: I downloaded the file `fd11src.iso`. To burn to a DVD, locate the file in the Finder application. Right click on the file and select **Burn Disk Image "fd11src.iso" to Disk...**. I use a RW DVD, which takes longer to burn, but is reusable.

Comment: I was able to burn the DVD to create an installer disk. Then, following the general set of instructions as found at http://freedos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox_-_Chapter_5, I can get to the point where it is about to install the FreeDOS kernel and that fails. I am attempting to install it to the second HD which is 250gb.

Comment: I also found these instructions - http://randomcomputerbits.blogspot.com/2008/02/tutorial-installing-freedos-on-intel.html but the results were the same.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I am not able to get it installed yet, but I am able to boot the FreeDOS installer from a DVD.

Comment: @ericgorr: I might try seeing if I can install FreeDOS on my 2007 iMac. First, I have to find a place to backup my Windows 10, just in case.

Comment: @ericgorr: We you get your computer to boot FreeDOS, your display should look like [this](http://imgur.com/wOkyGp2). Well, at least this is what my iMac displays.

Comment: When I boot from the DVD, it goes to the installer as shown in the first step here http://freedos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox_-_Chapter_5